# How to set UIView size based on superView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm looking to size a UIView relative to the superView.

The view needs to be centered to the superview, both vertically and horizontally.

I want to use originalContentView because of iAd

```
@IBOutlet var WhiteBar: UIView!    
WhiteBar.frame = CGRect(origin: MainView.center, size: CGSize(width: 280, height: 280))
```

Comment: Why not use auto layout

Comment: I spend a lot of time fighting but it is just a pain in the ass. Because I want these views to change based on screen size.

Comment: I'm a big fan of doing everything using SB but even I have to give up. if Eric  Gu was here he would be shocked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my final solution

I defined the width and height then subtracted it from the superview center. And loaded it in the viewDidLayoutSubviews()

```
        var Width: CGFloat = 280
        var Height: CGFloat = 280
        WhiteBar.frame = CGRect(x: (self.originalContentView.center.x - (Width / 2)), y: (self.originalContentView.center.y - (Height / 2)), width: Width, height: Height)
```

This adjust the view based on orientation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in your viewController, which takes a view, a set height, and a set width as a parameter and adds the following `NSLayoutConstraints` to the view's superview. You'll have to call this function after your view is already attached to the superview or it won't work.

```
func center(v: UIView, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {
    v.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    v.superview?.addConstraints(
        [
            NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: v,
                attribute: .CenterX,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: v.superview,
                attribute: .CenterX,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: 0
            ),
            NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: v,
                attribute: .CenterY,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: v.superview,
                attribute: .CenterY,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: 0
            ),
            NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: v,
                attribute: .Height,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: nil,
                attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: height
            ),
            NSLayoutConstraint(
                item: v,
                attribute: .Width,
                relatedBy: .Equal,
                toItem: nil,
                attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
                multiplier: 1,
                constant: width
            )
        ]
    )
}
```

Comment: Wow whats all this? Can't I just use the superviews origin as my center and give it a width and height?

Comment: With my code, I get it to be the right size based on screen size but its not centered

Comment: This is autolayout. It connects all edges of your subview to your superview so that no matter what size  your superview is, it will always be exactly as big.

Comment: do you mean centered? you have a typo in your question. I'll update with the right constraints

Comment: I'm not following. I want my view to be entered relative to the superview but different sizes based on screen size. I got the second part, now i just need to center it.

Comment: By the way, my view is not custom. I created it using SB, referenced it to an IBOutlet and using that with my code above

Comment: that's fine. I edited it so you can stick the function in your viewController and pass in your outlet and the width and height you want.

Comment: So are we saying there is no easier way to achieve this? why doesn't what I want to do work?

Comment: This may seem verbose to you, but it's always going to return the results you're looking for. Embrace autolayout. Once you put the time into learning it, it will make your whole life easier. Trust me.

Comment: I can show you that I really put the time into it. but it just doesn't work for what I want. Maybe we can chat on skype and ill show you what I'm talking about

Comment: You're telling me you've got a parent container and you want your subview centered in the parent container. Right?

Comment: Haha that would be easy. I can show you why Im doing the above instead of using auto layout

Comment: Ah, OK. Relative sizing. I get it. How big in relation to the superview do you want it?

Comment: OK. what's your skype.

Comment: My Skype is aelalfy1989

Answer (score 0):

You can use Autolayout (see other answers) or go to with struts: To use relative frames, it is better to use **viewWillLayoutSubviews**. Hope that helps.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        customSubView.center.x = view.center.x
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I got my code to work and it's similar to hay you stated